# $scope.$watch too slow when updating scope variable inside controller

Tags: angularjs

Here is part of code in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('date', function (newDate, oldDate) {
   ...
});
...
window.addEventListener('updateDate', updateDate);
function updateDate(date)  {
   $scope.date=date;
}
```

The template view is empty so there are no bindings. `updateDate` is a custom event dispatched from another application which co-exists with AngularJS under the same `window` object. The problem I have is there is a delay between the execution of `$scope.date=date` and the callback of $scope.$watch. However, that's not the case the first time 'updateDate' is dispatched; no delay!
After that first time, I got this delay.

Moreover, if applying a binding in the template and trying to update `$scope.date` from there, everything works fine.

Finally, by replacing `$scope.date` with the body of the callback of $scope.$watch, everything works fine again. However, the right thing to do is to update `$scope.date`...

1. Is there any explanation for the above behaviour?
2. Any solution?

Comment: maybe angularjs change detection did not find it, can you try running it manually using [`safe apply`](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js) after you set the `$scope.date` in the event listener, just a suggestion!

Comment: Close this question :) you're welcome